# How to call back a dynamically created element in java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, for-loop, return-value

E.g. I have this code which is going to create 10 dynamic objects
Then how can I call them back (e.g. getting their values, setting their values etc..)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    EditText test = new EditText(this);
    test.setHint("Your Input Here");
    // etc...
    Layout.addView(test);
    // A layout that I already made in XML file
}
```

So there after creating them how can I get their values which are going to be numbers that I want to add them to each other... or doing something else.

Comment: store them somewhere (list, array, etc.)

Comment: Put them into a collection, e.g. an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store them in something.
In your case, I would use an array.

```
EditText[] tab = new EditText[11];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    EditText test = new EditText(this);
    test.setHint("Your Input Here");

    tab[i] = test
    Layout.addView(test);

}
```

Then access it with

```
tab[i]
```

PS : For your `for` loop start `i` at 0, it will be better for memory management

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the easiest way is to store them inside Collection. Another way is to call `layout.getChildAt(position)` inside loop but then you will get all Views stored inside this `Layout` so you'll need to check what kind of View this is by:

```
for (int position = 0; position < layout.getChildCount(); position++) {
    if (layout.getChildAt(position) instanceof EditText) {
        // some action
    }
}
```